# .NET 5.0 generate exe for both Windows 32bits and 64bits

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

using VS 2019 Community on Windows 10 x64

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFrameworks>net48;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
        <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net5.0-windows'">
        <OutputPath>..\..\release\client\</OutputPath>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
        <AssemblyName>app-client</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

output : `app-client.dll` and `app-client.exe`

`app-client.exe` works on Windows 7 x64 but does not on Windows 7 x86

`dotnet app-client.dll` works on both Windows 7 x64 and Windows 7 x86

how to make `app-client.exe` works on both Windows 7 x64 and Windows 7 x86?

Comment: A `dll` file type is a dynamic link library, meant to export class libraries and code to other solutions. When we reference libraries, such as nuget packages, we are bringing in external DLL's and allowing our code to utilize their functionality.

I am unsure how you are able to run them, but a .dll is not an executable that should be shipped at all

Comment: do you have non-.net dependencies that depend on the bitness? the clr does the work

Comment: fyi .net 5.0 is out of support

Comment: The .exe is the problem, that's the apphost that launches the .net runtime.  Unmanaged code, you'll get the x64 flavor when you target AnyCPU.  You either need to launch c:\program files\dotnet\dotnet.exe instead or build the x86 target if 32-bit code execution needs to work.

Answer (score 1):

You more that likely need to publish your app. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/).

The new .NET executables do not have a concept of an exe that is both x32 and x64 like .NETFramework did.

You have to publish your exe as x32 or x64. Or if you want a truly cross-platform binary, then you have to rely on using `dotnet run <your_app>.dll` which requires the .NET runtime be installed.

The MSDN page I linked goes over everything thoroughly.